# How to pass parameters to an reactJS application

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a reactJS application.  When I test the app on my development machine I launch the application with npm start.  Based on my webpack.config.js file, the entry into my application is index.js.  I would like to launch my application and provide it with two pieces of data, similar to the way you can start Word from a command line and pass it parameters instructing it to open with a particular word document.

Thank you.

Comment: What are those two pieces of data? I'm not an expert but if you don't clearly explain your situation nobody can help :) For example, are they just variables and you want to use them somewhere in your application? Then, the environment variables are the way to go.

Comment: The application allows for the user to log into a legacy mainframe system. What I need to do is allow a third party company to make use of my application to log their participants into the legacy system. So they will be passing 2 unique pieces of data to my application. My application will recognize those pieces of data as coming from the third party and then go through an abbreviated login. We are trying to offer the 3rd party users a single signon process. So I need to take in parm1 and parm2 into my application.